# Vaadin 20 starter project with errors in pom.xml

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, vaadin, pom.xml, parent-pom

What I did:

- I went to start.vaadin.com
- I selected "Vaadin 20" and "Java 16"
- I downloaded and extracted the project

When I open the project in IntelliJ IDEA, I get three errors in the `pom.xml`:

1. Line 19, definition of parent: *Project 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.4.6' not found*
2. Line 143, `vaadin-maven-plugin` for `prepare-frontend` build goal: *Plugin 'com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:20.0.1' not found*
3. Line 164, production profile with `vaadin-maven-plugin`: *Plugin 'com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:20.0.1' not found*

The Maven Central repository is configured in the `pom.xml` file as a repository and as a plugin repository. Using my browser I can find the `vaadin-maven-plugin` in version `20.0.1` in the repository: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vaadin/vaadin-maven-plugin/20.0.1

When I change the version of the `vaadin-maven-plugin` to `19.0.7` and the version of the `spring-boot-starter-parent` to `2.4.5`, the errors disappear and the dependencies could be found.

I am not behind a proxy and I don't have a firewall running on my computer. I use Apache Maven 3.8.1 and AdoptOpenJDK 16.0.1.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, the problem was related to IntelliJ IDEA. The fix was really easy:

Menu "File > Invalidate Caches", select "Clear file system cache and Local History" and "Clear downloaded shared indexes", click on "Invalidate and Restart".

Looks like some cache or index files of IntelliJ got corrupted. Opening the project after the restart took a little bit longer because IntelliJ needs to reindex everything, but the three errors in the `pom.xml` are gone.

Sorry, I totally forgot about the caching of IntelliJ…

Answer (score 1):

If Maven has failed to load dependencies for whatever reason then you might need to run `mvn -U` for it to retry from the network instead of only the local cache

Comment: And at least for the plugin, it's not downloaded until it's needed, so IntelliJ will show an error until then if it's not already in your local repository.